# Getting different results from print and return

Tags: python, json, lambda

I'm currently developing a lambda in python and I'm actually a little bit struggling with building jsons in python.

The lambda reads from a dynamodb-table and adds all returned values to a json structure.

This works like a charm for printing that json, but not for returning it as callback.

Samplecode:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    jsondata = '{' \
        '"cols": [' \
            '{"id":"","label":"Timestamp","pattern":"","type":"string"},' \
            '{"id":"","label":"Temperature","pattern":"","type":"number"},' \
            '{"id":"","label":"Humidity","pattern":"","type":"number"}' \
            '],' \
        '"rows": ['
    jsondata += ']' \
        '}'
    print jsondata
    return jsondata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lambda_handler(None, None)
```

it seems to me that this "string addition" is not the smoothest way, but it was the only one that worked for

while the print looks as expected:

[image: log output]

the return value contains backslashes, which are making the return value unusable for me.

[image]

Since the application is only printing on shell, it is displaying the values correctly:

[image: shell output]

Any ideas?

Cheers and thanks in advance,
matthias

Comment: The return value doesn't contain backslashes, it just displays them because whatever environment you are using it in, displays string literals with double-quotes, thus has to escape double-quotes inside the string. On a diff. note, why do you not use the `json` package that you are importing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string doesn't contain backslashes. Its *representation* does, because it has to show that the string (which is delimited by `""`) doesn't end at that occurence of `"`. If you had to write a quote inside a string literal delimited by the same quote, you'd have to escape it with a backslash too.

That said, it's easier to build json with the `dumps` function from the `json` module:

```
import json

jsondata = json.dumps({
    "cols": [{"et": "cetera"}],
})
```

Comment: thanks both of you - It really worked for forwarding it to google chart. But a kind of strange behaviour....
@RemcoGerlich I've seen that possibility, but I didn't catch the bonus against building it as a string, since I didn't found any solution to extend an existing jsondata. e.g. appending one more value and to add a sublevel e.g. having A and adding later B with its sublevels

```{
 "A": 1,
 "B": [{
  "a": 1
 }, {
  "b": 2
 }]
}```

Comment: @MatthisR.Wiora: you first build a normal Python dictionary, which you can change and extend until it's perfect, and then only at the end do you call json.dumps to turn it into a string.

Comment: I'll try that - THANKS!